# ¿error string convertir a numero?

Tags: c++, c

```
char linea[] = "15,16777215,-,-";
```

Tengo que convertir el primer y segundo valor en dos variables de esta cadena,
una que sea igual a `15` y la otra igual a `16777215`.

Este es mi código pero no me guarda el segundo valor.

```
 #include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    
  char linea[] = "15,46777215,-,-";
  cout<<linea<<endl;
  
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  char nro[10]; 
  int numero1 = 0;
  int numero2 = 0;

    while(linea[i] != ','){

        nro[j++] = linea[i++];
        nro[j] = '\0';
        numero1 = atoi(nro);
        

         
     }

      j = 0;

    while(linea[i] != ','){

        nro[j++] = linea[i++];
        nro[j] = '\0';
        numero2 = atoi(nro);
        

     } 
     
     cout<<numero1<<endl;
     cout<<numero2<<endl;


    return 0;
 }
```

Pero solo me esta guardando el primer valor.

[image: COMPILACION]

Comment: Al hacer `linea[i++]` estas incrementando el valor de `i` y más abajo nuevamente incrementar su valor `i++` por lo que al comparar `linea[i]!=','` dará `false`  ya que `i` vale 2

Comment: Estas incrementando `i` 2 veces. Tendria que ser solo `linea[i]`.

Comment: @Pablochaches osea que quito el i++?

Comment: Estás en C++. Considera usar strings de C++ a menos que usar strings de C sea una necesidad. También cuenta con conversiones: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol

Comment: O quitas el `i++` al final de loop, o cambias `linea[i++]` por `linea[i]`.

Comment: @Pablochaches gracias, ya hice la edición pero ahora no me quiere guardar el segundo

Comment: `nro` no es lo suficientemente grande para guadar el segundo. Ademas de que el `nro[j] = '\0';` tiene que ser antes de la conversion.

Comment: @Pablochaches entiendo que el 'nro'  debe ser mas grande pero no entiendo lo de antes de la conversión, ya edite el código, podrías dejar una respuesta?

Comment: Ya asi como lo colocaste ya deveria funcionar la conversion de los numeros. Lo unico es que cuando terminas el primer while, no incrementas `i`, entonces cuando vayas al segundo while no vas a entrar porque sigues en la `,`.

Comment: @Pablochaches y como podría hacer para que quede después de la coma

Comment: @Pablochaches y como podría hacer para que quede después de la coma sin hacer i++;

Comment: No se porque quieres hacerlo de sin `i++`, si es lo mas simple. Pero si no quieres hacerlo asi, siempre puedes hacer `i += 1` o `i = i + 1`. Esto iria luego del `j = 0`

Comment: @Pablochaches no me hice entender,como puedo hacer para que cuando se acabe el primer bucle me pase a la siguiente posiciones después de la coma ?

Comment: Luego del `j=0`, colocas el `i++`, o cualquiera de las otras opciones que te mencione.

Comment: @Pablochaches hay alguna forma que ese i++ este dentro del bucle ?

Comment: Pues en primera instancia no se me ocurre una forma. Y de haber una no te la recomendaria, colocarlo luego del `j=0` es lo mas simple y facil de entender.

Answer (score 0):

Después del primer while(), i queda apuntando a la posición de la coma que rompe ese bucle, al revisarlo el segundo while, sigue siendo una coma lo que encuentra, por lo que no se ejecuta su contenido.

Agrega i++; despues de j=0; justo antes del segundo while()

**Et voilá**

Comment: Si la idea es analizar toda la cadena, tu código puede mejorar mucho. Un solo while() para revisar toda la cadena, dentro un if() para validar si encontró una coma, mientras tanto, guardar todo lo encontrado en el arreglo nro[], si hay coma, agregar el terminador \0, y guardar la conversión de nro[] a int en un arreglo int de Numeros con indices j.

Comment: gracias,hay alguna otra forma de hacerlo integrando el i++; en el algoritmo para que no tenga que quedar por fuera del bucle,osea que automaticamente me quede despues de la coma

Comment: Podrías adelantar ++i en el segundo while

      j = 0;

    while(linea[++i] != ','){

        nro[j++] = linea[i];
        nro[j] = '\0';
        numero2 = atoi(nro);

     } 

PERO.... ojo con esto, no estás validando el largo de la cadena y solo incrementas i, en algún momento, llegarás al final de la cadena, si no encuentra otra coma antes del final.